# Gcloud compute ssh --zone=us-east1-d --ssh-flag="-D" --ssh-flag="10000" --ssh-flag="-N" "spark-01-m" is not working

Tags: apache-spark, ssh, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

When I use the following command to set the ssh tunnel, I am getting the below error and I am unable to resolve it.

command:  `gcloud compute ssh --zone=us-east1-d --ssh-flag="-D" --ssh-flag="10000" --ssh-flag="-N" "spark-01-m"`

```
C:\Users\ssv1>gcloud compute ssh --zone=us-east1-d --ssh-flag="-D" --ssh-flag="10000" --ssh-flag="-N" "spark-01-m"
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) You do not currently have an active account selected.
Please run:

  $ gcloud auth login

to obtain new credentials, or if you have already logged in with a
different account:

  $ gcloud config set account ACCOUNT

to select an already authenticated account to use.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Feio0.png)

Comment: The error message tells you what to do. Did you try following those instructions? What happened?

Comment: Note: using special flags for SSH typically does NOT work on Windows. Read the documentation for Putty which is the program that gcloud launches. However, you need to correctly set up the Google Cloud SDK first. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-windows

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue is related to your lack of credentials, as per the message you got:

> You do not currently have an active account selected.
>   Please run:
>
> > $ gcloud auth login

The command [google auth](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login) requires authentication from your Gmail / gSuite account or a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts).

For Gmail account you simply need to run the command already mentioned to you and follow the steps that follows after that:

> $ gcloud auth login

As for service account then you must use:

> gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file="file.json"

Additionally, I would also recommend setting your desired GCP project with the following command:

> gcloud config set project <[project-id](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#identifying_projects)>

After that you shouldn't see the error message anymore but you might find the issue @john-hanley mentioned.